# PHP show full list of errors in a array

Tags: php, oop

I use OOP and i wanted to ask you guys how this would be done! I keep trying but its still not working ;(
Here is my class file:

```
class Signup {
    // Error
    public $error = array();
    public function validate($username, $email_mobile, $password) {
        if(!empty($username) || !empty($email_mobile) || !empty($password)){
            if(strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 50){
                $this->error = "Username is too short or too long!";
                return $this->error;
            }elseif(strlen($email_mobile) < 3 || strlen($email_mobile) > 50) {
                $this->error = "Email is too short or too long!";
                return $this->error;
            }elseif(strlen($password) < 3 || strlen($password) > 50){
                $this->error = "Password is too short or too long!";
                return $this->error;
            }
        } else {
            $this->error = "Please fill are required feilds";
            return $this->error;
        }
    }
```

Here is my signup file

```
$error[] = $signup->validate($username, $email_mobile, $password);
        <?php 
        // require('lib/function/signup.php');
        if(isset($error)){
            var_dump($error);
            foreach ($error as $value) {
                echo $value . "<br>";
            }
        }
        ?>
```

I know That im calling the $error in the same file and not the property error. But i dont know how to send this array to the other file! Please help me! Also i have Called everything and the problem is just with my code(i think), i only included my file and made a var to call my signup class

Comment: you don't envision a time where username, email and password may all be either too long or too short?

Comment: What is `$signup`? I guess it is an instance of `Signup`, but we do not see how you instantiate it. Inside `Signup` you declare errors as an array but then assign a string to it in either of the branches. Your `validate` function will always return a string, not an array. But on `signup` file you expect the result to be an array.

Comment: Not related, but you could move `return $this->error` outside all the conditional branches since it does not depend on the execution flow, you call it in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is never too early in your development career to study coding standards. Jump straight to PSR-12, and adopt all of these guidelines to write beautiful, professional code.
2. Use data type declarations in your classes where possible, it will improve the data integrity throughout your project(s).
3. You appear to prefer returning an array of errors.  For this reason, I see no benefit in caching the errors long-term in a class property. This coding style is fine to do, but you *could* choose to return nothing (`void`) and instead populate a class property `$errors`, then access it directly after the `$signup->validate()` call via `$signup->errors` or use a getter method.
4. The `empty()` checks are too late in the flow.  Once the values have been passed to the class method, these values must already be declared.  For this reason `empty()` is needless overhead to check for mere "falsiness". Just check the values' string length.
5. Your data quality checks seem a little immature (email and password checks should be much more complex), but I won't confuse you with any new complexity, but I do expect that your validation rules will increase as you realize that users cannot be trusted to put good values in forms without be forced to do so.  For this reason, it is probably unwise to use a loop to check the value lengths because you will eventually need to write individual rules for certain values.

A possible write up:

```
class Signup
{
    public function validate(
        string $username,
        string $email,
        string $password
    ): array
    {
        $errors = [];
        $usernameLength = strlen($username);
        if ($usernameLength < 3 || $usernameLength > 50) {
            $errors[] = "Username must be between 3 and 50 characters";
        }
        $emailLength = strlen($email);
        if ($emailLength < 3 || $emailLength > 50) {
            $errors[] = "Email must be between 3 and 50 characters";
        }
        $passwordLength = strlen($password);
        if ($passwordLength < 3 || $passwordLength > 50) {
            $errors[] = "Password must be between 3 and 50 characters";
        }
        return $errors;
    }
}
```

When calling this method...

```
$signup = new Signup();
$errors = $signup->validate(
    $_POST['username'] ?? '',
    $_POST['email'] ?? '',
    $_POST['password'] ?? ''
);
if ($errors) {
    echo '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $errors) . '</li></ul>';
} else {
    echo 'No errors';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should **add** elements to the array, instead of overwriting it, and returning, on all the branches.

```php
class Signup {
    
    public $errors = [];

    public function validate($username, $email_mobile, $password) {

        if (empty($username)) {
            $this->error[] = "Username cannot be empty";
        } else {
            $strlenUsername = strlen($username);
            if ($strlenUsername < 3 || $strlenUsername > 50){
                $this->errors[] = "Username is too short or too long!";
            }
        }

        if (empty($email_mobile)) {
            $this->error[] = "Email cannot be empty";
        } else {
            $strlenEM = strlen($email_mobile);
            if ($strlenEM < 3 || $strlenEM > 50) {
                $this->errors[] = "Email is too short or too long!";
            }
        }

        if (empty($password)) {
            $this->errors[] = "Password cannot be empty";
        } else {
            $strlenPass = strlen($password);
            if ($strlenPass < 3 || $strlenPass > 50) {
                $this->errors[] = "Password is too short or too long!";
            }
        }

        return $this->errors;
    }
}
```

If you always keep the same constrains for the three fields, you can shorten it:

```php
class Signup {

    public function validate($username, $email_mobile, $password) {

        $errors = [];
        $fields = [
            'Username' => $username,
            'Email' => $email_mobile,
            'Password' => $password
        ];

        foreach($fields as $key => $value) {
            if (empty($value)) {
                $errors[] = "$key cannot be empty";
            } else {
                $strlen = strlen($value);
                if ($strlen < 3 || $strlen > 50) {
                    $errors[] = "$key is too short or too long!";
                }
            }
        }

        return $errors;
    }
}
```

The above code guesses at what you are trying to do, if you just wanted a fix for not getting any results on `$error` see the original answer below.

#### Original answer.

Updating your code to this should give you the results you expect.

```php
class Signup {
    // Error
    public $error = array();
    public function validate($username, $email_mobile, $password) {

        if (!empty($username) || !empty($email_mobile) || !empty($password)){
            $strlenUsername = strlen($username);
            $strlenEM = strlen($email_mobile);
            $strlenPass = strlen($password);

            if ($strlenUsername < 3 || $strlenUsername > 50){
                $this->error[] = "Username is too short or too long!";
            } elseif ($strlenEM < 3 || $strlenEM > 50) {
                $this->error[] = "Email is too short or too long!";
            } elseif ($strlenPass < 3 || $strlenPass > 50){
                $this->error[] = "Password is too short or too long!";
            }

        } else {
            $this->error[] = "Please fill are required feilds";
        }

        return $this->error;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that, since you are using `if-else` you will always have, at most, one element in the array, it is hard to tell what you are trying to do with certainty, so I didn't change the logic and just fixed the most obvious problem.

If you want to **add** error messages to the array, get rid of the `else` keyword on the conditionals.

If you want to only receive **one** error message, consider using a `string` instead of an `array`.

Comment: Please cache the string length, so php doesn't have to repeat the same action for the same result.  I do not endorse the use of `!empty() || !empty() || !empty()` ...this is either flawed or excessive processing.

Comment: Just wanted to say something! All and all its really good! I also recommend not using ifelse because if the if is correct the others wont be executed. Tbf this is a foreach but just saying